# Get directory dynamically with python script

Tags: python, terminal, directory

I run my python script in the background from a terminal with:

```
python myscript.py &
```

In the script I have a loop which gets the current directory with os.getcwd(). If I change my working directory in the terminal though, the script doesn't get the new directory because as far as I have understood the script is attached to the original directory from which it was launched.

How can I update the current directory from a python script, i.e. how can I keep track of the current working directory of the process that launched the script?

Comment: A slight correction to your question in the final paragraph. **Terminals** don't have a current working directory. **Processes** do. So your question is "*How can I keep track of the current working directory of the process that launched the script?*"

Comment: If you have this sort of requirement, you are doing something that could be done in a much cleaner way (possibly).

Comment: im curious why the heck you would want this? im pretty sure that there is a better way to get to the desired end result ...

Comment: Regardless of whether it is a good idea, I wonder if you could monitor `/proc/<os.getppid()>/cwd`, maybe like so: `os.readlink('/proc/{}/cwd'.format(os.getppid()))`

Comment: So, I'm trying to make a game where your character moves inside the file system. Also, I'd like the game to run silently in the background and the only way to do stuff is to actually call commands in the terminal. Like you can move with cd or craft objects with touch, etc.

Comment: @Rob That actually worked, do you want to make an answer out of your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:*  don't do this.

```
import os
import subprocess
from time import sleep

ppid = os.getppid()

print "parent process id: ", ppid
subprocess.check_call(['pwdx', str(ppid)])
sleep(5)  # do `cd other` in the parent process here
subprocess.check_call(['pwdx', str(ppid)])
```

Comment: Thanks, wim. Can I ask you why is this such a bad idea?

Comment: It just seems weird for a child to know about the parent process state.  And you'll have to handle the case where the parent process terminates, that won't be easy to do without concurrency..

Comment: I was thinking of throwing an exception in that case and close the program

Comment: But you can't do it just with polling, or relying on the ppid not being found, because you have no guarantee that a new process hasn't spawned up and taken the same PID